# Cant store data from database but i can read from it

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Hello I'm trying to store the email data from the database to asp or html. I was able to read the data but then when I add the code Set storeEmail = Response.Write bs("email_addr") its giving me a error message Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'

Expected end of statement

/login/reset_form.asp, line 44

Set storeEmail = Response.Write bs("email_addr"). Here is my code :

```html
 DIM objConn, bs, ossql
    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Data Source=**"
    ossql = "SELECT email_addr FROM user WHERE username = '" & strUsername & "' AND system_code= '" & strHealth & "' AND facility_code = '"& strFacility & "'"
    Set bs = objConn.Execute(ossql)

    DIM storeEmail
    Set storeEmail = Response.Write bs("email_addr")
```

Comment: You really need to parameterize your queries. These are wide open to sql injection attack. My guess is you have a single quote in one of your string variables. And btw, using response.write does NOT put the column in the database, it displays it on the page.

Comment: @Sean Lange so you saying response.write doesn't store values? it only gives you right to displays on the page? my sql are right, I tested in oracle and it works fine. I can read but cant store value.

Comment: Response.write will NOT store values in Oracle. Response.write is a method of the Response object that is used to insert html into the httpresponse. If you want to insert data you have to run an insert statement. And do yourself a favor and do not disregard my comment about sql injection. Your code is a textbook example.

Comment: response.write doesn't assign value to a variable. Try                                   Set storeEmail = bs("email_addr")

Comment: @Saba I did that before and gives me an error ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'

Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

/login/reset_form.asp, line 44 storeEmail = bs("email_addr")

My record are still there

Comment: You really should read up on this, when you get an error, do a search with the error message first http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-bof-or-eof-errors.html , will give you and idea about the first error that you got

Answer (score 0):

response.write adds content to the output stream

If you are trying to assign a value to a variable then don't use "set" and don't use "response.write" like this;

```
dim storeEmail
storeEmail = ""

if not bs.eof then
    storeEmail = bs("email_addr")
end if
```

Comment: I did that before and gives me an error ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'

Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

/login/reset_form.asp, line 44 storeEmail = bs("email_addr")

My record are still there

Comment: That message would only occur if you didn't get a recordset back with at least one record.

In that case you should verify you have a recordset first. I expanded my comment to include that check.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DIM objConn, bs, ossql
    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Data Source=**"
    ossql = "SELECT email_addr FROM user WHERE username = '" & strUsername & "' AND system_code= '" & strHealth & "' AND facility_code = '"& strFacility & "'"

    response.write "SQL: "& ossql
    response.flush       

    Set bs = objConn.Execute(ossql)

    IF NOT bs.EOF THEN

         DIM storeEmail
         Set storeEmail = Response.Write bs("email_addr")

    END IF
```

What does the SQL say? Do any results come back at all?What comes back when you run the SQL against the DB?